# Is data driven oozie possible? - in theory

Tags: oozie

I know there are many question regarding how to make oozie what's a time driven workflow to data driven and an idea just came to my mind:

So here's my theory (I'm not using oozie syntax just try to explain the ):

```
<start to="action1" />
action1
    poll a data folder for new unprocessed files (wait for new data)
    <ok to="action2" />

action2    
     process data 
     <ok to="action1" />
```

Is there anybody tried this? Is oozie restricts recursive action calls?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Oozie workflows have to be [directed and acyclic graphs](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a2_Workflow_Definition).
You can work around this restrictions using sub-workflows, but it's really not a good thing to do.

A better solution to this may be to define [coordinator jobs](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a5._Dataset) to run if a dataset becomes available.